# A characterization of functions that preserve weak-majorization ordering

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding what should be a simple proof of a result in [Marshal and Olkin's book on majorization](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Inequalities_Theory_of_Majorization_and.html?id=I9wfajyOrooC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Inequalities: theory of majorization and its applications). Specifically, I'd like to understand Theorem 3.A.8 of that text.

I'll first state the necessary definitions for studying majorization. Given vectors $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the vector $y$ is said to *weakly majorize* the vector $x$ (denoted $x\prec_{\rm w}y$) if 
$$
x^{\downarrow}_1 + \cdots + x^\downarrow_k \leq y^{\downarrow}_1 + \cdots + y^\downarrow_k
$$
for all $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, where $x^\downarrow$ is the vector obtained by rearranging the entries of $x$ in decreasing order. The vector $y$ is said to *majorize* $x$ (denoted $x\prec y$) if $x\prec_{\rm w}y$ and  $x_1+\cdots +x_n = y_1+\cdots + y_n$. A function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be *Schur convex* if the implication
$$
x\prec y \,\Rightarrow\, \phi(x)\leq \phi(y)
$$
holds for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover, $\phi$ is said to be *increasing* if 
the implication
$$
x\leq y \,\Rightarrow\, \phi(x)\leq \phi(y)
$$
holds for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, where $x\leq y$ is taken entrywise (i.e. $x_k\leq y_k$ for each $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$).

Consider now the following characterization of functions that preserve the weak majorization order (c.f. Theorem 3.A.8 in Marshal and Olkin).

**Theorem** (Marshal and Olkin, 3.A.8). Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function. The following are equivalent:

1. $\phi$ is increasing and Schur convex
2. For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, if $x\prec_{\rm w}y$ then $\phi(x)\leq \phi(y)$.

The text does not give an explicit proof. I don't understand the explanation given in the text, and I can't quite figure out how to prove this myself. Any help in explaining or a concrete proof would appreciated.

Edit: I should mention that the proof of $2\Rightarrow 1$ is easy. Indeed, if either $x\leq y$ or $x\prec y$ hold then $x\prec_{\rm w}y$ also holds. The part that I don't understand is how to prove $1\Rightarrow 2$.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a nice explanation on my own. The following result is due to Ando (1989), where it is given as Corollary 1.8. It has a simple proof by induction.

**Lemma** (Ando (1989)). Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be vectors satisfying $x\prec_{\rm w}y$. There exists a vector $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $x\leq z\prec y$.

The proof of the direction $1\Rightarrow 2$ of the theorem in my question is now trivial. Indeed, suppose that $\phi$ is increasing and Schur convex and let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be vectors satisfying $x\prec_{\rm w}y$. There exists a vector $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $x\leq z\prec y$, and thus
$$
\phi(x)\leq \phi(z)\leq \phi(y).
$$

The original explanation in Marshal and Olkin is terrible, and I'm rather surprised that they didn't use this simple proof!

---

References:

T. Ando. [Majorization, Doubly Stochastic Matrices, and Comparison of Eigenvalues](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379589905806/1-s2.0-0024379589905806-main.pdf?_tid=8dcbc239-4103-4355-bebc-8eb370f96141&acdnat=1523580878_4ccd650f89db06b96b6abdea4416831e). Linear Algebra and its Applications 118:163-248 (1989).